# Why is gdalwarp changing value in nodata pixels?

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, modis, pymodis

I'm using gdalwarp to convert MODIS NDVI mosaics from Sinusoidal to epsg:4326. To save space I'm using VRT files until I reach the final product. Here is my workflow.

1. Mosaic NDVI Modis tiles using [pyModis](http://www.pymodis.org) and output as VRT. NoData value (-3000) is kept
2. gdalwarp the VRT mosaic to epsg:4326, tiff output. Pixels with NoData recieve value 0

My gdalwarp command is:

```
gdalwarp -t_srs epsg:4326 -tr 0.002 0.002 modis_mosaic.vrt reprojetc_mosaic.tif
```

Gdalinfo on the reprojected file shows that NoData values are kept (-3000) but nodata pixels in the image are converted to 0.
I'm using gdal 1.11.1 in Ubuntu linux

Answer (score 2):

Doing some more searching I found out that a bug related to gdalwarp and NODATA was fixed in version 1.11.2.

http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/Release/1.11.2-News

http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/5675

Testing on another machine with gdal 1.11.2 worked.

Answer (score 1):

Strangely, it look's like `gdalwarp` is missing the input vrt NoData declaration (well somehow still it declares it in output tiff...).

Which is a bit odd since you said that in step 1. the NoData value is kept. Check if element `<NoDataValue>-3000</NoDataValue>` exist for each band of your VRT dataset.

Beside above isue, you can try to force gdalwarp to use -3000 as NoData val with `-srcnodata` and `-dstnodata` parameters:

```
gdalwarp -t_srs epsg:4326 -tr 0.002 0.002 -srcnodata -3000 -dstnodata -3000 modis_mosaic.vrt reprojetc_mosaic.tif
```